# Gitlab's "Clear Runner Caches" missing for developer user(s)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

We are running permissions re-ordering. Moving teams to smaller groups in order to achieve it, and I created three groups as well:

- Reporter
- Developer
- Maintainer

For users under `developer` rank, the button `Clear Runner Caches` has gone missing. How can I allow every user to execute this option?

*Screenshot:*

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It's currently available only for `maintainers` and `owners` roles.
Nevertheless, there's an open ticket to allow `developers` to execute this command as well.

Refer: [GitLab Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/221634)